# The connection was not supported by oFono

Tags: lubuntu, powerpc

I have Lubuntu 13.10 on PowerMac G4(PowerPC). I installed `kubuntu-desktop`. Then restarted computer. I connect my modem and I am have this error :

```
"The connection was not supported by oFono"
```

How to fix this ?

Previously worked until I installed kubuntu-dekstop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how about previous Ubuntu versions but since 14.04 it's NOT modem-manager any more.

Now You have to use:

```
sudo apt-get purge ofono
sudo apt-get install modemmanager
```

and reboot. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Huawei E3131 on Ubuntu 13.10. Solved by:

```
sudo apt-get purge ofono
sudo apt-get install modem-manager
```

Unplug and plug your modem .

Now after around 5-15 seconds your OS should recognize the modem and you should be able to play with it (via Network Manager). In my case dialog requesting PIN number appeared. You can `tail -f /var/log/syslog` before and after above steps to see if you're a step closer.